# Battery Level using System Management in C#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, batterylevel

So I'm working on a speech recognition program in C# and I'v compiled a few lines of code that `speaks back the current battery level` when I say `"battery Level".` Only problem is, It doesn't work.

Debugging stage it builds fine, no errors or warnings yet when I say "battery level" I get no response.

```
if (e.Result.Text == "battery level")
        {
            System.Management.ManagementClass wmi = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
            var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();
            String estimatedChargeRemaining = String.Empty;

            foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
            {
                estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToString(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
            }

            JARVIS.Speak("Estimated Charge Remaining: " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "%");
            return;
        }
```

**Does anyone notice any obvious mistakes in the code that could prevent it from working?**

Thanks.

Comment: is the e.Result.Text in lower case? if not do this e.Result.Text.ToLower() == "battery level"

Comment: Are you sure recognition even works? Where does `e.Result.Text` come from? Try writing it to the console outside of the `if`-Block.

Comment: @Ehsan Ullah, Thank you, Your fix worked, Marked answer as accepted.

Comment: @bidifx, Yep, It works, I didn't put my full code in the original post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your code that may or may not be affecting your application

```
if (e.Result.Text.ToLower() == "battery level")   //First Change
{
    System.Management.ManagementClass wmi = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Battery");
    var allBatteries = wmi.GetInstances();
    String estimatedChargeRemaining = String.Empty;

    foreach (var battery in allBatteries)
    {
       estimatedChargeRemaining = Convert.ToString(battery["EstimatedChargeRemaining"]);
       JARVIS.Speak("Estimated Charge Remaining: " + estimatedChargeRemaining + "%");  //second change as you may have more than one batteries.
    }       
    return;
}
```